# Data form models is not shown in controller even if exist (Yii 2.0.6)

Tags: json, model-view-controller, yii2, models, dataprovider

I have this peace of code in my controller where I want to echo on the screen the JSON result for the data in the model:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new TestTableSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    var_dump($dataProvider->getModels());

    echo json_encode([
        "searchModel" => $searchModel,
        "getCount" => $dataProvider->getCount(),
        "dataProvider" => $dataProvider->models
    ]);
}
```

So `$dataProvider` actually is not empty and it contains the data (which can be seen from `var_dump()` command), but the data are not returned as I'm expecting.

Even `$dataProvider->getCount()` is returning that there are two entries. This is the output that I got: http://prntscr.com/8hcel9.

**I'm interested in showing the dataProvider part, where the items in array should not be empty.**

Comment: Maybe, need use $dataProvider->getModels() instead $dataProvider->models .

Comment: @ТохаМихайлов I have tried with $dataProvider->getModels() and it is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  convert the object to array

try this way :

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

......
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new TestTableSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    var_dump($dataProvider->getModels());

    echo json_encode([
        "searchModel" => $searchModel,
        "getCount" => $dataProvider->getCount(),
        "dataProvider" => ArrayHelper::toArray($dataProvider->models),  // object to Array 
   ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has not much to do with Yii. It's just a PHP problem. You can solve it like this (according to [this](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php#102091)):

```
echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode([
    "searchModel" => json_readable_encode($searchModel),
    "getCount" => $dataProvider->getCount(),
    "dataProvider" => json_readable_encode($dataProvider->models)
]);
echo "</pre>";

function json_readable_encode($in, $indent = 0, $from_array = false) {
    $_myself = __FUNCTION__;
    $_escape = function ($str) {
        return preg_replace("!([\b\t\n\r\f\"\\'])!", "\\\\\\1", $str);
    };

    $out = '';

    foreach ($in as $key => $value) {
        $out .= str_repeat("\t", $indent + 1);
        $out .= "\"" . $_escape((string)$key) . "\": ";

        if (is_object($value) || is_array($value)) {
            $out .= "\n";
            $out .= $_myself($value, $indent + 1);
        } elseif (is_bool($value)) {
            $out .= $value ? 'true' : 'false';
        } elseif (is_null($value)) {
            $out .= 'null';
        } elseif (is_string($value)) {
            $out .= "\"" . $_escape($value) . "\"";
        } else {
            $out .= $value;
        }

        $out .= ",\n";
    }

    if (!empty($out)) {
        $out = substr($out, 0, -2);
    }

    $out = str_repeat("\t", $indent) . "{\n" . $out;
    $out .= "\n" . str_repeat("\t", $indent) . "}";

    return $out;
}
```